# scanf() not working after ENTER

Tags: c, scanf

I'm making this simple example from server to client where the server functions as a echo server! So the client gets input from the user and sends it to the server, the server then sends it back.

I just got stuck on the input from the user. I used stuff like getchar, scanf and fgets. But when I start typing and press ENTER, then it should continue to the next thing in the program... Sadly that ain't happening.

Here is my code for the message part:

```
while(1)
{
    char message[1000], servermessage[1000];

    printf("You: ");
    scanf("%s", message);
    printf("%s\n", message);

    if (send(sock, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0) 
    {
        printf("sending failed\n");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int received = recv(sock, servermessage, sizeof(servermessage), 0);
    if (received < 0) 
    {
        printf("received failed\n");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    servermessage[received] = '\0';
    printf("Server: %s\n", servermessage);
}

close(sock);
```

Comment: What is happening after `scanf()`?

Comment: I can like keep typing the whole time... It never stops.. It like my stdin if f*cked up!

Comment: I think since your in a while loop, it appears to be always stuck at the scanf but its really not, have you tried gdb

Comment: So your issue is **not** to "*send message from client to server*" but that "*scanf does not work*", isn't it?

Comment: Yea kinda.. Oeps! I tried debugging but I just won't go further then the scanf...

Comment: Take your `scanf` before the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you type the first time, you call `recv()`, it will block until there is some data to read, you client didn't read any data, so nothing happen. You need check your echo server to find what's wrong. If you need a echo server to test your client, you can use the code for server [here](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs50/echoServer.c).

Comment: Oke, you might be right, but I don't understand why it won't run right now

Comment: Well you are the best! You were right about the recv in the server! I had the flag on MSG_WAITALL, changed it back to 0 and it works great :D Hero of the day!